# + sign in html and php

Tags: php, html, ascii

I have two buttons on my html page one of its value is + sign and another is - sign. I am sending those two variables to a php pge when they are clicked.here is my php page codes

```
if($value == "-"){
   echo "-";
}elseif($value == "+"){
   echo "+";
}else{
   echo "nothing";
}
```

When i click - button its echo

> -

but when i click + button it echo

> nothing

. Is there something wrong with + sign between php and html?

I am sending it via ajax like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     
     
          $(".pulse").on('click', function() {
               var id3 = $(this).data('id3');
               var value = $(this).attr('value');   

            var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();


                                                                 
            XHR.open("POST","point.php",true);
            XHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            XHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
                  if(XHR.readyState == 4 && XHR.status == 200) {
                           document.getElementById("n").innerHTML = XHR.responseText;
                       }
            }

            XHR.send("id3="+id3+"&value="+value);

            });             
         

</script>
```

My html

```
<div><input data-id3="'.$id3.'" class="pulse" value="+" type="button" style="background-color:rgb(153,153,51)"></input></div>
        <div class="puls"><input data-id3="'.$id3.'" class="pulse" value="-" type="button" style="background-color:rgb(204,51,51)"></input></div>
```

Comment: "I am sending those two variables to a php pge" — How?

Comment: Post your `HTML` code too ! ( I doubt there is a white space around your `+` )

Comment: Post the output of `var_dump($value);` for the case when you click the "+ button".

Comment: Are you sending the data urlencoded? a `+` has special meaning in a URL (often used to indicate a space)

Comment: check what data you are getting in POST using print_r($_POST);

Comment: There is nothing wrong how i send it cause when i click - i get a - again but when i click + i get the else statement

Comment: @MarkBaker please give me more information im sure + has somthing wrong in it

Comment: you cannot send sinle '+' symbol. it is used in urlencoded strings, as operator in javascript and php.. it will be prohibited i thin.. try to alter your code and send someting else

Comment: Show your HTML form, show how you are sending that form to the back-end PHP script

Comment: you can not user value + it is use to append variable in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` means "a space" in a URL (and also in application/x-www-form-urlencoded data). You have to encode your data with `encodeURIComponent`

```
XHR.send(
    "id3=" + 
    encodeURIComponent(id3) + 
    "&value=" +
    encodeURIComponent(value)
);
```